# Submitting form when losing focus

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically created form with a submit event listener attached to it, so I can do some ajax requests to save the data.

But I also want to submit it when losing focus.

I make the call `form.submit()` but the event listener, previously created, is ignored.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event_handler) {
    event_handler.preventDefault();
    /* some code */
});

// if loses focus
form.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
   form.submit(); // submits, but ignores the defined eventListener so the preventDefault() is ignored.
   return false;
}, true);
```

I was expecting that form.submit() would run the code defined inside the submit listener.

Any way to go around this.

No jQuery or any other frameworks. Just vanilla js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem indeed.
When you call JavaScript form.submit() it will override at times the event listener.
The simple solutions is just to have a submitter function call and call it.

```
 function runBeforeSubmit()
 {
     /* some code */
 }


 form.addEventListener('submit', function (event_handler) {
    event_handler.preventDefault();
    runBeforeSubmit(); <------------------------ shared code to process before submit
 });

 // if loses focus
 form.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
   runBeforeSubmit(); <------------------------ shared code to process before submit
   form.submit();
   return false;
}, true);
```

Comment: indeed it does work. I could override js built-in method for the submit event, but seems way overkill. I had hopes someone knew some trick, without resorting to repeating code (although it's just a single line).
Thanks. Answer accepted.